# Laravel Query taking too much time to load. How can I optimize this query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

I have Mysql query in Laravel application it takes 10-15 seconds to load the data:

```
DB::table('product')
    ->Join('product_attribute', 'product.product_id', '=', 'product_attribute.product_id')
    ->leftJoin('product_stock',function($leftJoin)use($seller_id){
      $leftJoin->on('product.product_id', '=', 'product_stock.product_id')
          ->where("product_stock.seller_id", "=", $seller_id);
      })
    ->where('product_stock.stock_id',$stock_id)
    ->select('product.*')
    ->orderBy('product_attribute.priority', 'ASC')
    ->get();
```

But when I remove this line of code it takes 100-150 milliseconds to load

code removed

```
->leftJoin('product_stock',function($leftJoin)use($seller_id){
      $leftJoin->on('product.product_id', '=', 'product_stock.product_id')
          ->where("product_stock.seller_id", "=", $seller_id);
      })
```

But I need to use the first code, how to optimize the above code to make it fast.
Thanks in advance

Comment: how about creating a mysql views ? FYI `https://www.guru99.com/views.html`. Also, reconsider if you need to select `*` from products table or just some columns. but have a look into mysql views.

Comment: The issue is with this code
->leftJoin('product_stock',function($leftJoin)use($seller_id){
      $leftJoin->on('product.product_id', '=', 'product_stock.product_id')
          ->where("product_stock.seller_id", "=", $seller_id);
      })

Comment: Why leftjoin with where clause is causing query to slow? Please help me out

Comment: does every `product` have `product_stock` records? and do u add index on product_stock's product_id and seller_id?

Comment: yes every `product` have `product_stock` and I have indexed all the ids

Comment: Try to use explain on the raw sql.